# Else not working in PHP

Tags: php

i have a problem with my code

```
$save = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['save']);
$query1 = "SELECT * from users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
$result = mysql_query($query1);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Get money from column
    $money = $row['money'];

    if($money >= $save)

        $query1 = "UPDATE users SET savings = savings + $save, money = money - $save WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];

        $update1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1); // call 1st query
        echo 'Money transferred successfully!!!';
    } else  {
        echo 'U NO MONEY IN CHECKING!!!!';
    }
?>
```

The else statement is not working and I am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in
>   C:\wamp\www\bank.php on line 44

Comment: `if($money >= $save)` should be `if($money >= $save) {`

Comment: @TheCodesee its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please see that you haven't opened a brace { after the if statement.

Change this:

```
if($money >= $save)
```

To:

```
if($money >= $save) {
```

Comment: Still not working bro

Comment: You haven't closed the while loop brace. Please close it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the opening curly-brace on the `if` statement:

```
if($money >= $save) {
    // Here --------^
```